# Param placeholder when using javascript bind function

Tags: javascript

I can use `bind()` to bind function and parameters.

For example, `outputTwo()` needs two parameters. I bind it with a parameter, then I only need to pass one parameter to it on calling. Looks like:

```
<script>
function outputTwo(param1, param2) {
    console.log(param1, param2);
}
var boundOutput = outputTwo.bind(null, "what"); // the first param should be an object, to replace <this> object in function, which not needed in our question
boundOutput("the heck?");
</script>
```

It will output `What the heck?`.

**Question is:** Can I bind the second parameter to `outputTwo()`, **without** binding the first one?

In C++, there is something called `placeholders`. When I need to bind param2 without binding param1, I need to pass a `placeholder` to param1, looks like:

```
auto boundOutput = std::bind(outputTwo, std::placeholders_1, "the heck?");
boundOutput("what");
```

It will output `What the heck?`. Is there something like this in javascript?

**EDIT:**
I'm writing a browser extension, and the function I need to bind, is written by me, but called by browser. So I'm not able to change the type of the parameter.

Comment: Downvoters: Please explain why? This seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: Indeed, nothing wrong with your question.  Explained well.  Anyway to the answer, bind will just go left to right.  But one neat feature of JS is object literals, if you pass using these you can create much more complicated default params.  `{first:"one"}`  and has the advantage of creating self documenting code from the callee side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it wouldn't be as nice:

```
const bindLast = (fn, this, ...lastArgs) =>
  (...firstArgs) => fn.call(this, [...firstArgs, ...lastArgs]);
```

You can do something similar with `Function.prototype` if you want to make it a method on function objects, I generally dislike doing that.

Usage:

```
const outputFirst = bindLast(outputTwo, null, "world");
outputFirst("hello"); // "hello world"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/** www.lsauer.com 2011
 *  http://www.lsauer.com/2011/08/javascript-using-placeholders-s-d-in.html
*/
var r = (r||{
  t : "check",
  m : "mate",
  c: 10.10
});
console.log('It is '+r.t+r.m+' for Player A. Game Stat:'+r.c);

//By using placeholders, the same example statement can be written more clearly, as follows:
console.log('It is %s%s for Player A. Game Stat: %d',r.t, r.m, r.c);
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/lsauer/2850506

As Keith said, this is equivalent if not better.